Bug with launching applications from the GNOME panel (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
Why do some applications (this happens periodically with chromium, thunderbird and firefox) sometimes run only the second or third time from the gnome panel? The first time you click on the icon, nothing happens, although the mouse pointer is in the loading state of the application for a while. This does not happen when running applications from the command line!
All problematic applications were installed from the Ubuntu Software.

I would check the System Monitor to see if it has crashed then kill it there and try to restart.
